# CSS selectors - how to target specific items

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm using grunticon to embed a different svg from a sprite sheet for each `span` with an `.icon` class.

I'm having trouble with the css selectors:

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="padding">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span class="icon svg-icon-1" data-grunticon-embed></span>
                <span class="title">Title 1</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span class="icon svg-icon-2" data-grunticon-embed></span>
                <span class="title">Title 2</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="icon svg-icon-3" data-grunticon-embed></span>
                    <span class="title">Title 3</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I've tried:

`.section li:nth-of-type(1) .icon`

`.section li:nth-of-type(2) .icon`

`.section li:nth-of-type(3) .icon`

but they are incorrect and using `nth-of-type` has performance implications. I have to target the `.icon` class and I can't use ids. The process is to add each selector to another encoding file which is configured to generate the svgs.

I'm not sure how to be more specific with the limited elements and restrictions. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Ummmm......maybe you could use an id?

Comment: If you only need to target the `icon` class, then what's wrong with the simple selector `.icon`? You're not mentioning any other requirements.

Comment: @Roope I've edited the original question. I want to target each `icon` class to generate a different svg background within the span tag.

Comment: You want to apply different css to each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need to target each `.icon` element separately, but don't want/can't use `nth-of-type`. You can try:

```
.section li .icon.svg-icon-1{}
.section li .icon.svg-icon-2{}
```

@edit

`.section li:nth-of-type(1) .icon` works for me.
[Demo](https://jsbin.com/honeni/edit?html,css,output)